# Is it possible to change text color and background color in the console to different colors while still on the same line? C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

Some of the solutions I've found don't seem to work on my terminal on Windows. Only changing the text to one color for the entirety of the line.
Example:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 0 | 15);
cout << 1;

hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,5 | 0);
cout << 2;
```

Only changes the text and background to one color.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: `std::cout` is buffered.  Try flushing it after each write.

Comment: With cout << xy << std::flush; ?

Comment: Perfect! flush made it work, Thanks a bunch! Been working on this for hours!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The reason it isn't working for you is because your code is wrong. You never set a background color; you just manipulate the foreground color.

The source of the problem is almost certainly the fact that you're using magic numbers (`0 | 15` and `5 | 0`) instead of the constants that are defined in `<Windows.h>`:

```
#define FOREGROUND_BLUE      0x0001 // text color contains blue.
#define FOREGROUND_GREEN     0x0002 // text color contains green.
#define FOREGROUND_RED       0x0004 // text color contains red.
#define FOREGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0008 // text color is intensified.
#define BACKGROUND_BLUE      0x0010 // background color contains blue.
#define BACKGROUND_GREEN     0x0020 // background color contains green.
#define BACKGROUND_RED       0x0040 // background color contains red.
#define BACKGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0080 // background color is intensified.
```

The following code works fine for me:

```
const HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// yellow on blue
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
std::cout << 1;

// blue on bright green
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY);
std::cout << 2;

// reset to black on white
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Here's a screenshot of my console window as proof that it works. (But note that my console's colors have been customized to the Tango theme, so yours will probably use slightly different colors.)

[image]

I recommend making life easier on yourself by defining an enum:

```
enum ConsoleColors
{
   BlackFore   = 0,
   MaroonFore  = FOREGROUND_RED,
   GreenFore   = FOREGROUND_GREEN,
   NavyFore    = FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   TealFore    = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   OliveFore   = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
   PurpleFore  = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   GrayFore    = FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   SilverFore  = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY,
   RedFore     = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED,
   LimeFore    = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
   BlueFore    = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   AquaFore    = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   YellowFore  = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN,
   FuchsiaFore = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
   WhiteFore   = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE,

   BlackBack   = 0,
   MaroonBack  = BACKGROUND_RED,
   GreenBack   = BACKGROUND_GREEN,
   NavyBack    = BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   TealBack    = BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   OliveBack   = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN,
   PurpleBack  = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   GrayBack    = BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   SilverBack  = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY,
   RedBack     = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED,
   LimeBack    = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_GREEN,
   BlueBack    = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   AquaBack    = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   YellowBack  = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN,
   FuchsiaBack = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
   WhiteBack   = BACKGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE,
};
```

and then set colors like this:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, ConsoleColors::BlackBack |
                                  ConsoleColors::RedFore));
```

Comment: I just copied the code directly and it compiles well enough, my console shows up normally though, with no color at all. It's in my main function. Do I need any specific headers aside from the ones you listed?

Comment: The only headers I used were `<windows.h>` and `<iostream>`. Very strange that it doesn't work. What version of Windows are you using? @max

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and Cygwin compiler in netbeans IDE. I'm compiling it, then running it outside the IDE though since colors don't show up inside the IDE.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I don't have Cygwin to test. This runs fine on all versions of Windows after compiling in Visual Studio. The compiler shouldn't matter, though. I don't suppose you have customized your console's colors so that they are monochromatic?

Comment: Nope, what's super bizarre to me is that the code in my original question changed the colors/backgrounds of the cmd output but when I use this it just stays black. Even if i change the #defines to 1 ,2 ,4 etc. I'm compiling it to an exe then running it in a folder with three dll's cygwin.dll etc since without those it won't run, if that makes any difference. Regardless, thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I didn't look at errors stupidly. Every #define is giving the error: /usr/include/w32api/wincon.h:120:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define BACKGROUND_GREEN 0x20

Comment: That error doesn't make sense. Oh, sorry. You don't need to include those `#define`s in your own code! I was just *quoting* from what is already in `<Windows.h>`. @max

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks a bunch for the help. The guys comment above mentioning std::flush makes your code work for me. Thanks a ton!